# Pootle and PO files: how to synchronize correctly?

Tags: django, localization, translation, po, pootle

We are having problems in synchronizing our PO files with Pootle:

1. Lost translations
   The first problem we encountered was that of lost translations. After doing an update_stores, some of our translations would be missing in Pootle. We have tried to remedy this with using the --keep option, but this had the adverse effect of not removing obsolete translations. We would like Pootle to hide obsolete translations, but not throw them away (the translation is obsolete, but still valid). Our current solution to this problem is to call sync_stores with the --overwrite option before calling make_messages
2. Wrong translations, not marked as fuzzy
   When we add a new message id to the PO file, Pootle will sometimes translate the message (using a bad translations, probably found using fuzzy matching) without activating the fuzzy flag.

Our current work-flow for synchronizing Pootle and our PO files is:

(adding new messages to pootle)

```
1. call "pootle sync_stores --overwrite" to update local po files with pootle contents
2. call "python manage.py makemessages -a" to add new messages to the po files
3. call "pootle update_stores" to import the latest po files in pootle
4. call "pootle update_translation_projects" to refresh pootle views
```

(updating po files with pootle contents)

```
5. call "pootle sync_stores --overwrite" to update local po files with pootle contents
6. call "python manage.py compilemessages" to create the mo files
```

The above tricks have reduced the number of errors somewhat, but we are still experiencing the above mentioned problems. Have you found similar problems? Have you been able to solve them?

Comment: We used to have similar problems with Pootle and in the end I've written Weblate (http://weblate.org/) which works better for us...

Comment: @mnieber Did you ever find a good solution for this? I'm struggling with this myself right now.